# How to sum values in between two range addresses

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that has the word "Circuit" 1,2,3..etc at the header on row 20. Each "Circuit" header has a variable number of columns below, depending on user input.

I'm trying to sum row 38 of this table until the next "Circuito" + number argument starts. I'm able to retrieve the start and the end of every range I want to sum. However, I can't find a way to sum the values.

```
For j = 1 To NumCirc 'NumCirc is the number of circuits
    Set rgfound = Range("B20:BZ20").Find("Circuit " & j)
    a = rgfound.Offset(18, 0).Address 'this is the first value
    b = rgfound.End(xlToRight).Offset(18, -1).Address 'this is the last value
Next j
```

Since I found the start and the end I expect to sum everything that is inbetween them. Worksheet.sum(a,b) only sums "a" and "b", but not all the values that are between in the range.

Can anyone give me an insight on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(a, b))` - but change `a` and `b` to `Range`s and `Set` them (get rid of the `.Address`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enclose `Range`s within a `Range` call - no need for addresses.

Change `a` and `b` to `Range`s and `Set` them.

```
Dim a as Range
Set a = rgfound.Offset(18, 0)

Dim b as Range
Set b = rgfound.End(xlToRight).Offset(18, -1)
```

Then

```
... WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(a, b))
```

---

**Other Notes**:

1. You should test if there is a range found:

   ```
   Set rgfound = Range("B20:BZ20").Find("Circuit " & j)

   If Not rgfound Is Nothing Then
       Set a = ...
       Set b = ...
       ...     
   End If
   ```
2. Best practice would be to specify which worksheet the `Range`s are on, unless you specifically want to work with the `ActiveSheet` - currently it is implied.